# How to create a shareable python distribution package that can be installed using pip?

Tags: python

I want to share my python code with my colleague in a way that he will get the distribution package and using pip the package can be installed on his/her machine.

I created .whl file which i thought can be directly installed through the pip install command.
Though it was installed successfully, when i start using it shows the error.

Is this possible like i give .whl file and it can be used in other's machine once installed through pip install command ?

I'm trying to do it on windows machine.

Here is the setup.py :

```
import setuptools
with open("README.md", "r") as fh:
    long_description = fh.read()
setuptools.setup(
     name='dokr',  
     version='0.1',
     scripts=['dokr'] ,
     author="Debapritam Chakra",
     author_email="debapritam22@gmail.com",
     description="A Sample package",
     long_description=long_description,
   long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
     url="",
     packages=setuptools.find_packages(),
     classifiers=[
         "Programming Language :: Python :: 2.7",
         "",
         "Operating System :: OS Independent",
     ],
 )
```

package that i am trying to create is dokr and have file named dokr in the same directory which has the content shown below.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
echo "hey there, this is a pip package"
```

used the command **python setup.py sdist bdist_wheel** to generate the distribution package.

To install package on my machine, I used the command :

**python -m pip install dist/name-of-wheel-file.whl**

It showed it is installed successfully(even checked using the **pip list**).
It throws the error when i try to import the package as

**import dokr**

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "", line 1, in

**ImportError: No module named dokr**

*Additional observation :*
Python on my machine is installed under C:\Python27.
After installing the package from whl file using pip, I could see there is a directory created under the path : C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\
named **dokr-0.1.dist-info**.For which pip list shows that the module is present.

But there is no such folder having the python file dokr itself, which i want to import in other python file. which shows error during importing.

I am new to python and this platform as well. Any lead would be helpful.

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: it better if you tells what error has occur and your setup.py file

Comment: assume the name of the package is wb2interface.

ImportError: No module named wb2interface

I checked using the command pip list if it is installed or not.

Comment: @DebapritamChakra you should add this error mentioned in comment to your post, this error mentioned in comments could be hard to find, as first thing people see is your post and not the comments.

Comment: @AJS appreciate your comment.
Now i have added it to post.

Answer (score 0):

Ofcourse, you can create a python distribution package.

Can you clearly show what is the error?
However, you can look into the following link!
 : [Packaging Python Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/)

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Fortunately found the cause of the problem.

I did not pass the argument( packages which takes the list of packages to be included ) in the setup function, for which packages could not be copied.

Following article and an awesome answer helped to sort out the issue.

https://setuptools.readthedocs.io/en/latest/setuptools.html#developer-s-guide

[pip install . creates only the dist-info not the package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585246/pip-install-creates-only-the-dist-info-not-the-package)

And I thank everyone who came here to help. :)