# Installing local package with pip install . doesn't work without -e flag

Tags: python, pip

I have written a small python package that I would like to install locally through pip. I used to do this by navigating to the package directory with the `setup.py` file, and then running `pip install .` after which the pip installer goes through the cycle and notifies me that it succesfully installed the package. When I check `pip freeze`, it is indeed listed there. However, when I then launch the Python interpreter and try to import my package, it throws a `ModuleNotFoundError`.

However, when I install through `pip install -e .`, this is not the case and it imports without problem.

I have used this approach already multiple times with other packages, but I can't seem to find why it keeps failing this particular time. I have already tried it with 2 different virtualenv's, verified I was using the right interpreter each time, but to no avail.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been able to address the problem! It is based on [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585246/pip-install-creates-only-the-dist-info-not-the-package).

I wrote a `setup.py` file, but in the `setup` part I did not include `packages=find_packages()`. Therefore, it only installed some information about the package, but nothing of the package itself. That was the reason why it showed up in `pip freeze`, but failed to import.

my setup now looks like this

```
setup(
    name='package name',
    version=__version__,
    description='package description',
    long_description=readme,
    author='my name',
    author_email='my mail',
    url='https://link_to_github_site.com',
    packages=find_packages(),
    license=license
)
```