# No module found 'psmpy'

Tags: python

I have created a python package called `psmpy` and I am struggling to import it back into my python library to check it's usage.

When I run, `from psmpy import PsmPy` I am getting the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp/ipykernel_12528/438942766.py in <module>
----> 1 from psmpy import PsmPy

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psmpy'
```

But the module is up on pypi.org and I can see it installed when I run `pip list` in the list of current packages installed. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: do you have a file named `psmpy.py` located in your current folder?

Comment: Can you provide directory list of your current folder and directory of `psmpy` package?

Comment: You probably have multiple python interpreters. Can you validate if you can see that in your site-packages directory?

Comment: How would I do these things from my jupyter notebook? Side note I am on a windows machine

Comment: It is installed in my base interpreter and the psmpy was installed through pip install psmpy. I don't want psmpy.py in my current folder. I want is a package I can import

Comment: It shows it installed: /opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages when I ran `pip show psmpy`

Comment: the problem is the way you have build this package. you need to go through and double check. Check this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/54357929/13202252