# pip install . only allows package to be imported when in the original directory

Tags: python, pip, package, setuptools, setup.py

I have a package that I have built locally and I wish to distribute for use in another package. After `pip install .` I am able to import this package and run functions in Python, but *only when in the original directory.* For example, immediately after installing the package:

```
>>> import mypkg
>>> mypkg.components.body_columns.dummify
<function dummify at 0x7fb380650e50>
```

However, as soon as I leave the directory, it can no longer be imported. For example after `cd ~/Desktop`:

```
>>> import mypkg
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'mypkg'
```

Additionally, at the install location, given with `pip show mypkg`, there is currently only a `mypkg-1.3.0.dist-info` directory and no `mypkg` directory. I have been trying to follow [this guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585246/pip-install-creates-only-the-dist-info-not-the-package), but no luck yet, and this seems like a distinct issue.

I am new to trying to distribute packages - any idea what is going on?

If helpful, the (simplified) hierarchical structure is:

```
mypkg
├── mypkg
│   └── components
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── body_columns.py
├── __init__.py
├── app.py
└── setup.py
```

The basal `__init__.py` reads: `from . import mypkg`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out. It was a basic issue related to where I placed my `__init__.py` files.

The proper file structure places the first `__init__.py` not in the root directory, but in the synonymous directory it houses:

```
mypkg
├── mypkg
│   ├── __init__.py
│   └── components
│       ├── __init__.py
│       └── body_columns.py
├── app.py
└── setup.py
```

The reason I was able to import with the correct directory is, obvious in hindsight, because I was in the same directory as the `mypkg` folder itself, i.e., I was just importing as one might import any script that is in one's current directory (though in this case it was the package).