# custom Python package seemingly installs but ModuleNotFound on import

Tags: python, setup.py, python-packaging, pyproject.toml

I am trying to turn my python code into a package.

I have the following structure

```
package_name
     src/
        __init__.py
        module/
            __init__.py
            code.py
        module2/
            __init__.py
            code2.py
            submodule/
                 __init__.py
                 code3.py
```

I've tried using both setup.py and pyproject.toml

My pyproject.toml looks like:

```
[build-system]
requires = ["setuptools>=42", "wheel"]
build-backend = "setuptools.build_meta"

[project]
name = "package_name"
version = "0.0.1"
description = "A description of my package"

dependencies = [
    'deps', 
    'deps2',
]
```

While the setup.py looks like:

```
from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='package_name',
    version='0.0.1',
    packages=find_packages('src'),
    package_dir={'': 'src'},
    author='my name',
    description='A short description of my package',
    install_requires=[
       'deps',
       'deps2'
    ],
)
```

When I run python3 -m build . (for the pyproject.toml) or python setup.py sdist (for setup.py) I get package.tar files as expected.

I can install these using pip, and both pip list and pip show show the expected result. (pip list includes package_name 0.0.1), pip show contains the following:

```
Version: 0.0.1
Summary: A description of my package
Home-page: 
Author: 
Author-email: 
License: 
Location: {venv_path}/site-packages
```

Looking at the module in site-packages, and all the code seems to be present as expected.

However, when I try and import my_package from within my venv, either from command line or in a script, I get a ModuleNotFound error. Every other package installed in the venv and in site-packages can be imported with no issues.

What could be going wrong? I'm sure I'm missing something obvious but really at a loss!

In case potentially relevant, I am running python 3.10.12 on Ubuntu 22.04

Comment: I think I've resolved my own problem, thanks to the answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50585246/pip-install-creates-only-the-dist-info-not-the-package. structure needs to be:
```package_name
     src/
          package_name/```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.